# Programmatically display simple prefs from window

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an add-on that inserts javascript/html into pages as you browse. One functionality is it saves the path of the directory you wish to save info to.

I want to provide a directory select control (inlined into the corner of each page using HTML), but Firefox does not support one for HTML5. You can only get a directory selector by using simple-prefs, which can only be reached by going through Tools->Add-ons->Specific add-on and clicking the browse button there.

I would like to be able to access the simple prefs directly by spawning a new tab or something similar from within the current window tab I'm modifying, without clicking through all the menus. Is there a URI I can use such as "about:addons:appname" or some other way to go about this?

Comment: HTML does offer a File explorer. just do `<input type="file">`. IF you don't like that method, from your add-on you're injecting stuff anyways, inject a button than `addEventListener` to it and on click make it launch [`nsIFilePicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFilePicker#Example). If you want to create an `about:` page follow the instructions here: [Creating custom about pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about:_URLs)

Comment: Ah thanks, nsIFilePicker did it...strange that I missed the modeGetFolder property.